# Assigning CPU cores to virtual machines

Tags: virtual-machine, cpu-usage

VMPlayer lets you select how many CPU cores to assign to the virtual machine. I changed it from one to two. Does that mean that those two cores will be used exclusively by the VM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it means that it will be able to assign tasks to two cores on the host, directly corresponding to tasks assigned to the two virtual cores within the guest.